# Add custom tag to ReverseProxyCache

Tags: shopware6

What is the correct way (if any) to add a custom tag to all cached pages?
Should I decorate `ReverseProxyCache` and add my tag in the `write` method?

PS: I use Varnish as reverse proxy so `VarnishReverseProxyGateway` kicks in, but maybe this is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [multiple instances of `StoreApiRouteCacheTagsEvent`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/search?p=1&q=StoreApiRouteCacheTagsEvent) which are dispatched in the respective class of the route. You may listen to these events and add tags to them in the subscriber. While there is no single  event that covers all routes, at least all of them extend the same class, so you may use a single method for all of them.

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ProductListingRouteCacheTagsEvent::class => 'onCacheTags',
        ProductSearchRouteCacheTagsEvent::class => 'onCacheTags',
        // ...
    ];
}

public function onCacheTags(StoreApiRouteCacheTagsEvent $event): void
{
    $event->addTags(['my', 'custom', 'tags']);
}
```